# error with the map Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary

I develop a simple mapActivity  that aska the user to check if he has enabled the gps system or not by using the dialog alert and the intent for the location service. And  if the gps is enables it goes direct to the mapView but this do not happen with me. It makes me force close when I press to go to the mapView.

This is the dialog code:

```
  public void onClick(View arg0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click yes TO ENABLE GPS")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, close
                                        // current activity
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
                                          startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  
                                          } 

                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                                        //dialog.cancel();

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.class);
                                        context.startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                });



                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }

        });



    }
```

And this is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    

package="com.mkyong.android"

 android:versionCode="1"


    android:versionName="1.0" ><uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AndroidGoogleMapsActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the code of the AndroidGoogleMapsActivity class

public class AndroidGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

```
@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Displaying Zooming controls
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    Log.d("error", "the negative button befor the line 27 ");
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Log.d("error", "the negative button after the line 27 befor the map view settings ");     

     mapView.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
     Log.d("error", "the negative button after the line 27 after satellite view  "); 
     mapView.setStreetView(false); // Street View
     Log.d("error", "the negative button after the line 27 after street view  "); 
     mapView.setTraffic(true); // Traffic view

     Log.d("error", "the negative button after the line 27 after  the map view settings ");  

    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    Log.d("error", "the negative button after the line 27 after  the mapController ");  
    double lat = Double.parseDouble("33.823862");// kehale
    double lon = Double.parseDouble("35.590248");// kehale
    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
    mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
    mc.setZoom(15);
    mapView.invalidate(); 

    Log.d("error", "the negative button befor the GeoPoint");


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

And this is the error that I get:

```
09-20 05:16:22.512: D/AndroidRuntime(309): Shutting down VM
09-20 05:16:22.512: W/dalvikvm(309): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.mkyong.android.AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.onCreate(AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.java:27)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-20 05:16:22.543: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 11 more
09-20 05:16:25.141: I/Process(309): Sending signal. PID: 309 SIG: 9
```

Comment: sorry guys I'm new to this forum thanks for the help

Comment: The issue is in your AndroidGoogleMapsActivity.onCreate() method, please post the code for the method along with line numbers if possible or else tell us what line is line 27 because that's where the NullPointerException is thrown

Comment: ok i edit my question with the class and i know that the error is in the line 27 but i don't know how to fix it  thank you

Comment: Please tell us which line of code is line 27. As in, what are the contents of line 27?

Comment: mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  this is the line 27 but i notice that all what is related to the mapView  plz help

Comment: btw Stack Overflow is not a forum. Forums are largely discussion-based and tend to follow less strict rules about what posts can be like.
On Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general), we require every new thread to be started with a question and every response to that question to be an attempt at answering it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you got a problem in your layout-file that causes this NullPointerException.

```
// This command tries to get the mapView but fails to find it, so it returns null, instead of the mapView
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
// This tries to call a method on null, which will cause a NullPointerException.
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

To solve this check that in your `layout/map_activity.xml` the map is actually named mapView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```